# ValidationForm message for specific types of errors

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When any of the form fields are not filled, I want the ValidationSummary to display the message "All fields are required", but when some other type of error occur (like a wrong e-mail format, or invalid date), I want it to display the full errors list.

For example:

```
Name: Raphael_________
Age: _________________
E-mail: me@example.com

"All fields are required."
```

but when all fields are filled, but one or more of them have invalid values:

```
Name: Raphael_________
Age: twenty-four______
E-mail: me at example.com

- The Age field has an invalid number;
- Please enter a valid e-mail address;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you need all this to happen as soon as user screen renders? or only after an attempted submit or a field content is erased and focus changed?

Comment: @DaveA, it should be displayed when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: I'm playing around with it. Not an easy req. I feel like I'm circling the answer, but missing something

Comment: @Raphael Try like this in your `@Html.BeginForm()`-- `@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "All fields are required")`. You should be able to get all the validation errors

Comment: @Karthik: I need the `"All fields are required"` *only* when some field is empty. When all fields have value, I want the specific formatting error messages to be displayed (like in the example).